# Connection to the database server failed

Tags: sql

I'm using sql server for the first time.

I've installed sql server 2008 R2, the problem is that I can't connect to the database server.

When I add my computer name as a server name, this error message appear:

> "Une erreur liée au réseau ou spécifique à l'instance s'est produite lors de l'établissement d'une connexion à SQL Server. Le serveur est introuvable ou n'est pas accessible. Vérifiez que le nom de l'instance est correct et que SQL Server est configuré pour autoriser les connexions distantes. (provider: Fournisseur de canaux nommés, error: 40 - Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

Translation:

> "A network-related error or instance-specific occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections (provider: named, channel error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server). (Net SqlClient Data Provider). "

Is there an other program that I must install ?

Comment: Is the MSSql service started?  Check your services.

Comment: Did you install full SQL Server or the express version? It looks like it is looking for the instance on your computer and doesn't find the default instance. so an example would be .\instancename. the . (dot) represents your local computer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've installed express version.is it necessary to install the full sql server?